# Duplicate local variable end + error if variable name changed

Tags: java, variables, duplicates

I have an error with the variable `MoveCheck` and `end`. It is an anticheat plugin:

```java
if (inc >= moves.size())
      {
        MoveCheck tmp235_232 = Instance; tmp235_232.getClass(); jumps.add(new Jump(start, (MoveLog)moves.get(inc - 1), (MoveLog)moves.get(inc - 1)));
        break;
      }

      MoveLog apex = (MoveLog)moves.get(inc - 1);
      boolean isFloating = false;
      boolean isOnFire = false;
      int floatCount = 0;

      while ((inc < moves.size()) && (((MoveLog)moves.get(inc)).isAir))
      {
        if (((MoveLog)moves.get(inc - 1)).location.getY() <= ((MoveLog)moves.get(inc)).location.getY())
        {
          floatCount++;

          if (floatCount > 3)
            isFloating = true;
        }
        else
        {
          floatCount = 0;
        }

        if (((MoveLog)moves.get(inc)).isOnFire) {
          isOnFire = true;
        }
        inc++;
      }
      MoveLog end;
      MoveLog end; //error duplicate variable -if rename end1 whith other end = error

      if (inc >= moves.size())
        end = (MoveLog)moves.get(moves.size() - 1);
      else
        end = (MoveLog)moves.get(inc);
      MoveCheck tmp433_430 = Instance; tmp433_430.getClass(); Jump jump = new Jump(start, apex, end);
      jump.isFloating = isFloating;
      jump.isOnFire = isOnFire;
      jumps.add(jump);
    }
```

Comment: Can we have some context for this please? Makes no sense without it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use the appropriate generic with your `moves` Collection (which I assume is a list) -

```
List<MoveLog> moves; // <-- something like that.
```

Second, you can use a ternary (I kept the casts, but if you do step 1 you don't need them) -

```
MoveLog end = (inc >= moves.size()) ? (MoveLog) moves.get(moves.size() - 1) : 
                                      (MoveLog) moves.get(inc);
```

You cannot have two variables named `end` in scope at once.